# How are piecewise cubic spline bases constructed?

Tags: splines, statistical-learning

There are words from the *The Elements of Statistical Learning* on page 119:

> It is not hard to show that the following basis represents a cubic spline with     knots at $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$:

- $h_1(X)=1$
- $h_2(X)=X$
- $h_3(X)=X^2$
- $h_4(X)=X^3$
- $h_5(X)=(X-\xi_1)_+^3$
- $h_6(X)=(X-\xi_2)_+^3$

Then my question is that, according to the numeric analysis, piecewise cubic polynominals tries to fit the function in region $[\xi_1,\xi_2]$ with polynomials at order 3, so I think the basis should be

- $h_1(X)=f(\xi_1)$
- $h_2(X)=(X-\xi_1)$
- $h_3(X)=(X-\xi_1)^2$
- $h_4(X)=(X-\xi_1)^3$.

There are at most 4 basis, so where am I wrong?

Comment: Which edition/printing do you have? It's on p143 in the [latest version](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) (2nd edition, 5th printing with corrections). There's more explanation there than you give above.

Comment: I have the first edition and content about piecewise cubic polynomial in second edition are similar with the related content in first edition. I just don't understand why the cubic basis are constructed in that way.

Comment: At the bottom, you give a basis for all cubic polynomials.  Although its *elements* depend on (one) of the knots, the space of functions they generate is *independent* of the knots.  Moreover, splines have more degrees of freedom than polynomials: they are allowed to change at each knot.  Depending on the type of spline, this adds *at least* one degree of freedom for each knot.  Therefore I would expect a basis of cubic splines with two knots to have a dimension of *at least* 4+2=6, exactly as stated in the quotation.

Comment: I don't understand **the splines have more degrees of freedom than polynomials: they are allowed to change at each knot**.  In my opinion, cubic splines are polynomials in each region with the three conditions at the knots. @whuber

Comment: I recommend watching the statistical learning videos at Stanford. The "Splines" videos really helped me understand them better. The text is DENSE.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Look at a simpler problem:** construct a basis for the space of piecewise *constant* functions whose values are allowed to break at the knots.  With two knots, that's three intervals.  One basis would consist of (a) the function that equals $1$ for all arguments less than or equal to $\xi_1$ and otherwise is $0$, (b) the function equal to $1$ for all arguments from $\xi_1$ through $\xi_2$ and otherwise is $0$, and (c) the function equal to $1$ for all arguments greater than $\xi_2$ but otherwise is $0$.  However, there's another way.  The idea is to let the basis elements encode the jumps that occur at the knots.  The first basis element therefore is a constant function, say $1$, *regardless* of the knots.   The second basis element encodes a jump at $\xi_1$.  It's convenient to take it to equal $0$ for values less than or equal to $\xi_1$ and to equal $1$ for larger values.  Let's call this function $H_{\xi_1}$.  The third basis element can be taken to be $H_{\xi_2}$.

For example, the piecewise constant function that jumps from $48$ to $-120$ and then to $240$ at knots $\xi_1 = 2$ and $\xi_2 = 4$ can be written as $48 -168H_2 + 360H_4$: in this form, it reveals itself explicitly as a jump of $-168$ at $\xi_1=2$ followed by a jump of $+360$ at $\xi_2=4$, after starting from a baseline value of $48$.

[image: spline 0]

*Here is a piecewise constant spline with two knots.  It is determined by its three levels or, equivalently, by a "baseline" level and two jumps.*

It should be clear that although the space of constant functions has dimension $1$, the space of *piecewise* constant functions with $k\ge 0$ knots has dimension $k+1$: one for a "baseline" constant plus $k$ more dimensions, one for each possible jump.

**Cubic splines are obtained by integrating piecewise constant functions three times.**  This introduces three constants of integration.  We can absorb them into the integral of the constant function.  This gives a "baseline" cubic spanned by $1$, $x$, $x^2$, and $x^3$.  Modulo these constants of integration, the integral of $H_{\xi}$ is $\frac{1}{3!}(x-\xi)_+^3$: its third derivative jumps by $1$ at the value $\xi$ and otherwise is constant (equal to $0$ to the left of $\xi$ and $1$ to the right of $\xi$).  The basis named in the quotation merely rescales these functions by $3!$.

[image: Spline 3]

*Here is a third integral of the preceding piecewise constant function.  Notice that no cubic polynomial possibly can behave this way (it cannot have two flat or nearly-flat sections).  Splines are inherently more flexible than polynomials of the same degree; they span a higher-dimensional space of functions.*

**It should now be obvious how to extend this formulation** to any number of knots and to any degree of splines.  Understanding the procedure can be useful when you need non-standard splines for specific problems.  For instance, I recently had to develop circular quadratic splines for a regression that involved an angular independent variable (an orientation in the plane modulo $180$ degrees).

Comment: (+1) It is interesting that the "right" *intuition* (like this) seems to so often be far removed from a reasonable *implementation*. I would hope no software actually uses the basis in the OP's question.

Comment: That's an interesting observation.  I have interpreted this question in the spirit of characterizing the entire vector space rather than selecting a suitable basis for it.  I think you could start with almost any basis you like and orthonormalize it before applying it to the data.  In practice, I believe certain bases are chosen for their *interpretability.*  For instance, one might replace the (potentially problematic) collection of $\{X^k\}$ by $\{(X-\mu)^k\}$ where $\mu$ is the center of the data.

Comment: If I look at $N_{i,0} = \begin{cases} 1, t\in [t_i,t_{i+1})\\ 0, \text{else}\end{cases}$ (which is a first order B-Spline) and integrate three times, I'll get $N_{i,0} =\frac{1}{6}t^3+\frac{1}{2}p_1+p_2t+p_3$ where $p_i$ are constants of integration from each step. I do not quite understand how you'll get $\frac{1}{3!}(x-\xi)^3_+$. Additionally to get a smooth, twice differentiable cublic spline function I would need to impose conditions on the first and second derivative. Looking at statistical text-books such as Wood - GAM in R, I dont quite get how a cubic spline basis actually looks like.

Comment: @Druss Expand $(x-\xi)_{+}^3$ using the Binomial Theorem to expose the relationship between it and the constants of integration. Re your second point: when you integrate a piecewise constant function, the result is piecewise continuously differentiable; another integration makes it piecewise twice continuously differentiable; and the third integration makes it piecewise thrice continuously differentiable. Thus, *there is no reason to impose any conditions on the derivatives* when constructing the splines this way.